# C# .dll library in Android app

Tags: c#, android, dll, xamarin.android

I'm currently using Monodroid to develop an android app. I'm rather new to phone apps so am confused over a couple things:

1. What by definition is an android library? I use the Mono template to create android library: Create a Mono for Android Class Library => write the code and build into .dll => run with emulator from Visual Studio and it works fine in the emulator. But is the .dll file a android library? Or it is converted by Mono before working on the emulator and the 'REAL' android library should be JAR?
2. Can I directly use my defined .dll written in C# to make this app? I tried it in Mono by directly referencing it in my android app and it is building, no errors.  But when the emulator run this app, it get stucked (still no error) - what is the right way to use c# .dll in Android app project?

I realize there are quite a couple topics discussing the link between c# and android and about mono but after reading I still cannot get around with this library referencing problem so if anyone could offer any hint/thoughts would be most appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The DLL generated is compiled against the [Mono for Android profile](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/assemblies), which is based on Moonlight (Mono's implementation of Silverlight). At runtime, .NET code is run directly against the Mono runtime which runs as [part of your application](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture). When .NET code subclasses something from the Java side (e.g. Java.Lang.Object), Mono for Android generates [callable wrappers](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture/android_callable_wrappers) to handle communication between runtimes.
2. Technically you can use a normal .NET DLL in your Mono for Android application, but I wouldn't recommend it. The profile exposed by Mono for Android is much smaller than that of the full .NET framework (and isn't even completely equivalent to that of Silverlight), so if your DLL references a method that isn't found in Mono for Android, your application will crash. Instead, I would recommend creating a separate class library for your application, and share source files across projects using file linking. My [blog post here](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/12/shared-libraries-for-windows-phone-7-monodroid-and-beyond/) contains an example of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer here! So since the .NET code is run against Mono runtime does that mean, the dll can only be used for android application, provided installed Monodroid SDK? Because my primary aim is not the application but to port some c# library to android library and provide them to android developers.. in that case, does that mean even if i successfully made the dll compatible with android, they still require Monodroid to do the runtime wrapping?

Comment: That's correct - a DLL compiled with Mono for Android will only be useful for applications built with Mono for Android.

Comment: If you want to offer a library to developers then you should have a dll compiled for that platform.  As long you only use the supported classes you can support multiple platform.  In theory **Math.Round** will work exactly the same on all platforms.  This assumes that the Mono implementation matches the Microsoft .NET implementation for all inputs ( it likely tests because they did unit testing on it ).

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean by supported classes? Suppose I'm using .NET classes supported by monodroid application - that is, they provide wrappers to handle these classes, is it possible I conpile a dll that support multiple platform? because for now I think it is impossible to have a dll that is valuable to all android developers (as most of them write their app in Java) and the only approach for me is to use Monodroid library project to build them into a JAR so the Java developers can use it.. Do you think there is a way a dll would do the job?

Comment: @LynnYiLu - What I mean by "supported classes" are the classes that Mono supports. There is no reason you could not do exactly what Monodroid does.

Comment: @GregShackles what if I stuck in this question with android native development and without using monodroid? my whole problem described here in this ques if you has an answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393305/using-dll-library-in-android-application