# Port .NET dll to different platforms

Tags: android, .net, ios, macos, dll

I have a dll based on .NET 2.0 with full source code access.
So I can build it in VS2010.

I need to port this to Android/iOS/MacOS.
As a result I expect some equivalent of dll for each platform.
So another programmer can link (doesn't matter how) this equivalent to his own project at one of that targeted platform.

For example I ran MonoDevelop on Mac and don't see how I can build my .NET project and to receive such equivalent of dll.

So I need help to find solution and understand what to do to receive requierd result.

Comment: Android supports native libraries via http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: I dont need another language, library's code is tooo big and complicated. i need the real porting of C# code, with a small changes if required

Comment: Android has no .NET and can't use .NET dlls unless you use MonoDroid to build apps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394722/c-sharp-dll-library-in-android-app

Answer (score 1):

There are CLI implementations, primarily Mono, that work on both iOS and droid. The simplest  tools here are MonoTouch and Mono for Android, both available from Xamarin. With these tools, you can build and test your dll targetting the relevant frameworks. Another programmer, again using the MonoTouch or Mono for Android tools, can reference those dlls, and build their application, with all the tools necessary to package and deploy (side-loading or via, say, the device's store) an application using that library. This deployment will typically also include all the runtime/framework pieces needed by the application.

MonoTouch makes use of the MonoDevelop IDE, so will be familiar to you as a MonoDevelop user. Mono for Android *can* do that (i.e. be hosted inside MonoDevelop), but can also be used inside Visual Studio.

Comment: So, the short answer is No ? I cant, by myself, create equivalent of dll for those platforms. All i can do, is to be sure my library's code is full compatible with Mono's IDE on every platform i need. Am i correct ?

Comment: @Alexander wait... I just told you *how you can do it* - how do you get "No" from that? It is very definitely not a "No". The only stop mandate here is that the consumer must be using similar tools, i.e. MonoTouch / Mono for Android. I have a number C# libraries that are in regular use on iOS / Android...

Comment: I cant rewrite my lib's code to objective-C or anything else. Its a huge library, so such idea is a waist of time. So i have only C# code for library VS2010 project. So what can i do ? I see i must be sure my code must compiled with no errors (i checked this about month ago). What else ? As i understood, i can only propose real dll to another programmer and he can use it with Mono. Right ?

Comment: @Alexander I didn't mention objective-C. I'm talking about regular C#. Heck, you don't even need MonoTouch/Mono-for-Android *yourself* unless you are going to run validation on emus / devices; you can just build it in Visual Studio. Targeting 2.0 is a good choice, as it avoids a lot of features that may not be available (WCF etc).

Comment: @Alexander in short, this *could* be as simple as "press build, give library dll to consumer". The consumer developer would need to be using MonoTouch / Mono for Android, but they just add a reference like normal, and *that's it*.

Comment: Ok, so i think i understood you. I must be sure the code i have will be compiled fine with MonoTouch/MonoDevelop/Mono for Android (i can test real Mono's IDE i think since compilation is free as i remember). And good idea is to have different versions of dll for each platform (with file links and/or #if directive). Right ?     Posted before saw last your comment :)

Comment: @Alexander they don't even need to build it if you don't want; you can just **give them the dll**. As for `#if` - well, that depends what your library is doing, but yes, `#if` is one way to do this. For example, one of my libs has to use this to avoid `Interlocked`, which isn't available on "unity" on some devices; and you might want to avoid excessive reflection usage. If you have a specific question on this, let me know - I have libs that work on: iOS,Android,Unity,CF2,CF3.5,SL4,.NETCore (aka WinRT),.NETPortable,.NET1.1,.NET2,.NET3.0,Windows Phone 7.1, Mono (full) and XNA!

Comment: My lib is also has a lot of targeted platforms, so i use #if sometimes for specific things. Thank you, its now clear for me. You are better than google's search :)

Answer (score 0):

Running .NET code requires a .NET runtime to be installed. Neither Android nor iOS devices come with such a runtime preinstalled.

In theory, you could install the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) Runtime (a open-source .NET alternative) on an Android device or a jailbroken iPhone/iPad. However, as I understand it, you're looking for a way to create a library to give developers, so this isn't a good solution.

However, what *could* work is creating a library with [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch/). MonoTouch compiles your .NET code to a binary that iOS devices can use - regardless if they're jailbroken or not, without needing a runtime installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow best practices, you might port your library successfully, such as

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/discussions/390251

However, it purely depends on the characteristics of your library, which you does not mention yet.