# Unity - How to use c++ dll?

Tags: c#, android, c++, dll, unity-game-engine

I have an AR application. I created a c++ dll using visual studio 2013. I use this dll in my AR application like below :

```
**In private members region :**
[DllImport ("DllExample")]
private static extern int func(int x, int y);
.......

**In a C# function :** 
if (func((int)pos.x, (int)pos.y) == -1) {
    ...
}
else {              
    ...
}
```

My unity application works fine unity editor. I build this app for android. When I run it on a android device, it doesn't work.

Content of C++ dll :

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>        
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int func(int x, int y);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}


__declspec(dllexport) int func(int x, int y)
{   
cv::RNG rng(12345);
cv::Mat image0, image, gray, mask;
int ffillMode = 1;
int loDiff = 20, upDiff = 20;
int connectivity = 4;
int isColor = true;
bool useMask = false;
int newMaskVal = 255;

return x;
}
```

In unity C# file, if I remove call dll function, the application works fine on my android device .I use free unity version. How can I use a c++ dll on a mobile device?

Comment: This site has some information on where you need to place you libraries in order to include them in the deployment of none desktop builds. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html However i would have thought you would need to rebuild your library under the compiler that matches your target system. 

EDIT: Found this SO answer if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394722/c-sharp-dll-library-in-android-app

Comment: @PaulHickman I can't see plugin region in inspector. I use free unity. Is it available on free version?

Comment: Appears that Native Unmanaged DLLs are only available in Unity Pro 4. I can't seem to find a clear reference for Unity 5. If i find anything i'll update...

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the dll file in your in the Android Plugin Folder for it to work. The Android plugin folder is **Assets/Plugins/Android**. Create it if it doesnt exit.

**EDIT:**
 Unity plugin is NOT available in non Pros according to my research. Unity plugin is supported in both free and pro Unity 5. You need to update to Unity 5. Here is a [link](http://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/allow-native-code-plugins-for-un) of person who made Unity to support plugin in Unity free version.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.  I use free unity. Is it available on free version?

Comment: My code includes opencv functions. I tried your method. But the application cannot run on android.

Comment: I just looked at your code. What is function func() suppose to do? It doesn't do anything other than creating variables. What do you expect to happen when func is called on the cpp side?

Comment: It is not a full code I want to test whether opencv works on android.

Answer (score 0):

Android runs on a Linux system - DLL files are usually bytecode compiled for Windows.

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793531/use-dll-files-in-android-application)